# How do Stack Overflow URLs work?

Tags: php, url

I have build URLs of my site like Stack Overflow URLs. My URLs are as below.

```
http://www.example.com/1255544/this-is-the-url-text
```

In this URL, `1255544` is the id and `this-is-the-url-text` is the URL title text, both stored in the database. I have noticed that Stack Overflow URLs work on the base of id. Suppose here is a Stack Overflow URL

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679171/new-way-to-prevent-xss-attacks
```

In this URL, `15679171` is the id of the post. When I changed this id to `15706581` without touching the `new-way-to-prevent-xss-attacks` and pressed Enter, the URL automatically changed  to the following URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706581/simplecursoradapter-does-not-load-
external-sqlite-database-id-error
```

And when I tried to remove some of the part of the URL title text like below

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679171/new-way-to-preve
```

It automatically corrects the URL as below:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679171/new-way-to-prevent-xss-attacks
```

It means the data is being retrieved from the database on the basis of id `15679171` and the relevant URL title text, `new-way-to-prevent-xss-attacks`, is attached according to the id.

I also want to do this. But the problem is, I am not going to understand that if someone change the id of the URL the title text should automatically changed. How do I do this?

I have thought the following:

```
$url_id = $_GET["id"];
$url_txt = $_GET["url_txt"];

$qry = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url_id = '{$url_id}' LIMIT 1";
$data = mysql_query($qry);
$data_set = mysql_fetch_array($data);

if($url_txt== $data_set["url_txt"]) {
    // proceed further
} else {
     $rebuilt_url = "http://www.example.com/" . $url_id . "/" . $data_set["url_txt"];
     header("Location: {$rebuilt_url}")  // Redirect to this URL
}
```

Is it the proper and efficient way to perform this action or not? Is there a solution?

Comment: when page load, get url from your database by id, compare it with url from address bar, if it's not the same, then redirect to right url.

Comment: Also, be careful of sql injection (casting $url_id to an int should do the trick).

Comment: Hi there. You recently posted a question called "How Stackoverflow Questions Answers System Works", and it was migrated to a different site in error by a moderator. Oops, smack for them `:)`. I suggest you repost it (use copy and paste!) but call it "How to optimise my StackOverflow-like system". Bear in mind that it might be closed as too discursive however, though you might get some general remarks in the comments. If you repost, ping me here (@halfer) and I'll comment.

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks pretty good and in one of my Stack Overflow answers I had also suggested similar approach. However, I suggest just one minor improvement. Instead of:

```
header("Location: {$rebuilt_url}");
```

You should do:

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header("Location: {$rebuilt_url}");
```

This will let browser cache these URLs aggressively and you code and SQL queries will not be executed every time.

**Also check:**

1. [.htaccess if URL is bad do something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816625/htaccess-if-url-is-bad-do-something/14816869#14816869)
2. [.htaccess rewrite friendly URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520671/htaccess-rewrite-friendly-urls/6520802#6520802)

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server), I think you must know about **[URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)**

In URL rewriting you rewrite the URL to a more friendly look. Take a look at the URL below

> http://www.downloadsite.com?category=34769845698752354

and when you do a URL rewrite on it, it became like this

```
http://www.downloadsite.com/Nettools/Messengers
```

URL rewriting needs to be set on the Apache configuration (rewriting rules) so it will rewrite your URL before request is interpret by PHP so you will get the exact resource you want to acquire

```
 RewriteRule ^/category$ /content.php  
  RewriteRule ^/category/([0-9]+)$ /.php?id=$1  
  RewriteRule  
    ^/category/([0-9]+),([ad]*),([0-9]{0,3}),([0-9]*),([0-9]*$)  
    cat.php?id=$1&sort=$2&order=$3&start=$4
```

Well, I can't explain you everything here, but below I provide you some links where you can learn about URL rewriting.

**This the best hack you can do to create friendly URLs!**

**Resources:**

- http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/
- http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2009/01/06/url-rewriting-with-apache-and-php-a-simple-example/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/
- [.htaccess rewrite friendly URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520671/htaccess-rewrite-friendly-urls/6520802#6520802)

Comment: Hi Mahan, it's customary on Stack Overflow to provide an example or explanation in the body of your answer itself. This ensures three things: If the link breaks, your answer will still be valuable to future visitors, and it ensures people only need to leave Stack Overflow if they need more in-depth information beyond the answer to the question.  Lastly, your example could be tailored, whereas the links are likely generalizations. You can use this [edit] link to make the additions. Hope this helps.

Comment: well there are a lot of ways in URL rewriting and every way has a long way to go so I just put some best links I found on the web. Well I will edit my answer

Comment: You don't have to show *every* possibility, but an example would keep your post from possibly being flagged as not an answer. Plus, examples help folks learn and increase the chances of your post getting more upvotes. Good luck! :)