# Htaccess 301 redirect htaccess or php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a rewrite rule in Htaccess as below for a dynamic URL

```
RewriteRule ^cartoon-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /fm
/cart_new?r_id=$1&location=$2 [L]
```

This rule results into URL as `http://localhost/fm/cartoon-34-singapore.html`

Now my client want to change this URL to `http://localhost/fm/singapore/34/goofie` and i wrote .htaccess as

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /fm
/cart_new?location=$1&r_id=$2&cartooname=$3 [L]
```

The above rewrite is working fine but client wants that all OLD URLs like i.e.`http://localhost/fm/cartoon-34-singapore.html` shall 301 redirect to `http://localhost/fm/singapore/34/goofie`.

This is driving me crazy. I have tried various things but none seems working.

Comment: Old URL `http://localhost/fm/cartoon-34-singapore.html` doesn't have `cartooname` in it. So it cannot redirect to `http://localhost/fm/singapore/34/goofie`

Comment: can we chnage URL somehow in PHP by sending 301 rediredct headers if URL pattern matches?

Comment: Yes it can be done in PHP and then do redirect in PHP itself

Comment: Can u please quote any example please?

Comment: [See tis answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15847193/548225)

Comment: Can u please add this as an answer so that i can accept same.

Comment: ok I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code you can do something like this for redirection:

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header("Location: {$rebuilt_url}");
```

Here `$rebuilt_ur` will be set to `http://localhost/fm/singapore/34/goofie` by querying your database.

Comment: Working like charm :)